# Same code leads to errors in different projects

Tags: typescript, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-api

I'm currently using the Power BI Visuals API to transfer my D3 chord diagram into a power bi visual.  I've been using the [Microsoft Chord GitHub Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-chord/) as a starting reference.  I'm creating the supporting classes, but I'm getting errors returned in my version even when I use the same code from the microsoft repo.

Looking specifically at the 'columns.ts' file, when I copy the code as is from the github, I get errors on the 'let varName: type = x' lines saying that undefined cannot be assigned to DataViewTable type.  But I cloned the entire repository from Microsoft, and I don't get those errors when I import their file directly.

Code is exactly the same.
[Cloned from GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOlhI.png)
[Copied from GitHub to my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5MEv.png)

I've tried adding try catch statements, if else checks, and I've also tried the non-null assertion operator where I can - but I still run into issues in the functions that return null.  I just don't understand why the same code will provide errors in one location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) enabled in your `tsconfig.json` whereas it doesn't appear to be enabled in [this repo's `tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-visuals-chord/blob/main/tsconfig.json).

*Note: This may also be listed as [`strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) which enables `strictNullChecks` as well as a number of other strict type-checking flags*

If that is the case, their configuration will have looser type checking rules (when it comes to `null`/`undefined` checking) than yours, effectively allowing assignment of `null` or `undefined` to any other type, even if it is not explicitly stated in the type definition.

Typescript Playgrounds:

- [`strictNullChecks` enabled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmA1AhgJwFxyhglmAOYwC8MArmACZIBmhS1QA)
- [`strictNullChecks` disabled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmA1AhgJwFxyhglmAOYwC8MArmACZIBmhS1QA)

If this is the case, you have the option to:

- Also disable `strictNullChecks` and accept the same loose typing rules
- Modify your local typing of the variables in question to be more representative (i.e. include `| null` or `| undefined` in variable definitions that could/should handle those values)

Comment: This was a great suggestion! I had "strict" set as False, which I thought would have solved it, but I checked the repo again and they completely omitted the line.  I got rid of the "strict" value all together and it seems to have solved it